# how to get recently viewed nodes using views in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

i want to show recently viewed nodes in drupal7. It is showing up for individual user only, i need it to show all the users recently visited the site. I used recently read and session_api but it is showing the nodes for particular users recently viewed nodes. I want it to display all nodes visited by all users(authenticated &anonymous)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: https://drupal.org/project/radioactivity

( introduction tutorial here : http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/radioactivity-2-basics/2011-12-05 )

It's pretty flexible, and should suit your use case

Comment: Agreed. It's probably one of my favorite modules to use.